# Spring - How to use resources in src/main in unit tests?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit

I have the following folder structure in my Spring application:

```
src 
\__main
\   \__resources 
 \_test
```

How can make use of the files in resources folder while unit testing the application? In otherwords, how can I load the files in src/main/resources folder into test-classes which gets created while executing tests?

Comment: You don't mention how you run JUnit. If you use Maven (your project structure looks like a Maven project), it should just work by default: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2978493/3801695

Answer (score 0):

You can create another folder by the same name, i.e "resources" under the test package. This is a standard resource folder under Maven. All the files under this folder is accessible to the test classes under the test package during runtime.

Comment: I don't want to make a duplicate copy of the files under resources folder. I want to access the ones inside src/main/resources.